# how to to set button horizontally in a center

Tags: ios, swift, button, autolayout

I am trying to create a button programmatically and want to have the button slightly above from the bottom and space from right and left. At the moment button is displaying like this

[image]

here is the code

```
func showbutton(){
        let button = UIButton(type: .System) // let preferred over var here
        button.frame = CGRectMake(8, 550, 415, 50)

        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        button.setTitle("Add new request", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        //button.addTarget(self, action: "Action:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        // Set background color to see if label is centered

        view.addSubview(button)

    }
```

Comment: Use AutoLayout constraints. I use [SnapKit](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit) to make code-based constraints not suck.

Comment: well I need to show and hide the button based on some conditions so I need to do it programmatically

Comment: Yep, that's why I mentioned SnapKit -- programatic constraints, but instead of having to write obnoxious, complicated constraint syntax, you can do it using their logical, block-based syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will place a space of 8 points on the Left and Right while keeping all your other dimensions the same

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
let screenWidth = screenSize.width

button.frame = CGRectMake(8, 550, screenSize.width-16, 50)
```

Comment: This does work, but the future of iOS dev definitely lies in AutoLayout. I highly recommend against adjusting frames in 2016.

Comment: @brandonscript yeah, obviously, use AutoLayout for as much as possible, I'm just answering the question in the simplest way possible, it's all good

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, my go-to for programatically using AutoLayout (and you should be using AutoLayout) is [SnapKit](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit).

```
func showbutton(){
    let button = UIButton(type: .System) // let preferred over var here
    button.frame = CGRectMake(8, 550, 415, 50)

    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    button.setTitle("Add new request", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    //button.addTarget(self, action: "Action:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)
    // Set background color to see if label is centered

    view.addSubview(button)
    // create the constraints
    button.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.centerY.equalTo(view)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the button's frame by adjusting the numbers, but you would lose autolayout features and when the screen rotates your button will not look right.

Instead add constraints, just like you would in the storyboard using the [NSLayoutContraint](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/) class.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

**By using UIView frame as a reference**

```
    import UIKit
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

            let rect : CGRect = self.view.frame
            let width  = rect.width
            let height = rect.height

            let buttonHeight : CGFloat = 50.0
            let leftMargin : CGFloat = 10.0
            let bottomMargin : CGFloat = 10.0

            let button  : UIButton = UIButton()
            button.frame = CGRectMake(leftMargin, height-buttonHeight-bottomMargin, width - 2*leftMargin , buttonHeight)
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            button.setTitle("Add new request", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            self.view.addSubview(button)
        }
    }
```

Solution 2:

**By using AutoLayout constraints:**

```
    import UIKit
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            let requiredButton : UIButton = {
                let button = UIButton()
                button.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
                button.setTitle("Add new request", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                return button
            }()

            // dont worry about frame right now

            self.view.addSubview(requiredButton)

            // set frame using autolayout

            self.view.addContraintsWithFormat("H:|-10-[v0]-10-|", views: requiredButton)
            self.view.addContraintsWithFormat("V:[v0(50)]-10-|", views: requiredButton)
      [enter image description here][1]
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }


    }


    extension UIView{
        func addContraintsWithFormat(format: String, views: UIView...){
            var viewDictionary = [String: UIView]()
            for (index,view) in views.enumerate(){
                let key = "v\(index)"
                viewDictionary[key] = view
                view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            }

            addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewDictionary))
        }
    }
```

**output same in both cases**